# angular4 router outlet override

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I'm using angular4 router. I have a layout page with a navbar and I want to use different navbars when visiting /admin/** and other pages. I set the global empty path with

```
{
    path: '',
    component: NavbarComponent,
    outlet: 'navbar'
};
```

and set the admin empty path with

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: AdminNavbarComponent,
            outlet: 'navbar'
        },
        ...ADMIN_ROUTES
    ]
}
```

But accessing admin pages ends up with error

> Cannot activate an already activated outlet

I thought maybe the admin empty path would override the global empty path because it matches the url mostly.

And I don't want to specify the outlet using the url like

```
http://.../admin(navbar:adminnarbar)
```

because if the user visits front page with http://...(navbar:adminnavbar) would render the admin navbar which is not desired.

In fact, I just want something like overriding a outlet like most template engine does.

Any idea How should I do?

Here is the [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/48cae40kahTJuS3zDBom/) Please help.

Comment: I think you should use RouterModule.forChild(routes)

Comment: I do use RouterModule.forChild(routes) in admin module.

Comment: Can you create a plunker and post the link

Comment: Here is the [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/48cae40kahTJuS3zDBom/). Please treat the about page as the admin.